# Extending a natural transformation using a distinguished triangle

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

$\require{AMScd}$

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category,
and $\mathcal{S}$ a full subcategory of $\mathcal{T}$ (which is not triangulated).

Let $F, G: \mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T}$ be two triangulated functors.

I have a "partial" natural isomorphism: 
For any $M \in \mathcal{S}$, I am given an isomorphism $\eta_M: F(M) \to G(M)$, such that if $f:M \to N$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{S}$,
the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
F(M) @>{F(f)}>> F(N)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
G(M) @>{G(f)}>> G(N)
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative.

Now, I am given two distinguished triangles
$$\mathbf{M} =  M' \to M'' \to M \to \Sigma M'$$
and
$$\mathbf{N} = N' \to N'' \to N \to \Sigma N'$$
with $M',M'',N',N'' \in \mathcal{S}$, but $M,N \notin \mathcal{S}$.

I am also given a morphism of triangles $\mathbf{f} = (f',f'',f): \mathbf{M} \to \mathbf{N}$.

Using the triangles $F(\mathbf{M}), G(\mathbf{M})$, and the isomorphisms $\eta_{M'}, \eta_{M''}$, 
I can obtain an isomorphism $\eta_M: F(M) \to G(M)$, and similarly an isomorphism $\eta_N:F(N) \to G(N)$.

My question:

Is it possible to choose the isomorphisms $\eta_M, \eta_N$ so that 
$G(f) \circ \eta_M = \eta_N \circ F(f)$?